# Invalid mime type "json": does not contain '/'

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente:

Intento replicar el llamado al siguiente api mediante la libreria RestTemplate de Java utilizando el framework Spring boot (spring-boot-starter-parent:2.0.9.RELEASE):

[image: Llamado mediante curl]

El código que tengo implementado es:

[image: java_code]

Las clases que viajan en el body del GET:

[image: clases]

Luego de realizar el llamado, arroja el siguiente error:

[image: error]

NOTA: Cuando realizo el llamado desde POSTMAN resulta satisfactorio.

[image: postman]

Me apoyé del suguiente post para realizar el código.

https://mekaso.rocks/get-requests-with-a-request-body-spring-resttemplate-vs-apache-httpclient

Agradecería mucho su colaboración mirando que podría estar haciendo equivocadamente.

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Jorge la parte del ejemplo en que te basaste el autor dice que no funciona `let me just point it out, that it did not work ` eso se debe a que según las convenciones los servicios REST GET no deberían te tener `BODY` y todos su parámetros deberían de viajar por la URL, pero como rest es una especificación  y no un estándar que te obligue a hacer los servicios correctamente, tienes el caso que el ` RestThemplate` no te permite enviar un `BODY` en la petición` GET ` porque el estándar que se acordó así define, por lo cual debes basar tu ejemplo en la parte final del tutorial `The Spring way`